# Vuejs vuesax upload image issue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create an [image upload with vuesax](https://lusaxweb.github.io/vuesax/components/upload.html#default). Simple enough....

```html
<div class="centerx">
  <vs-upload
    limit="1"
    text="Upload Primary Photo"
    required
    id="primaryImageUploadId"

  />
</div>
<div class="centerx">
  <vs-upload
    multiple
    text="Upload Secondary Photos"
  />
</div>
```

I'm using something like what is above. It looks great and I can upload images, the issue is how they set up that component to work is it just automatically is supposed to upload the images or files to some url that you give it. That's definitely not what I want to do haha, as far as I can tell they provided no way of getting the files from this component and then uploading all of them at once into the form. There also doesn't appear to be a way to require that files must be input. Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `action` (where you want to send the files) and `fileName` (the name under which you want to send the files) attributes.

ex:

```
      <vs-upload multiple automatic text="Drag you photos here" action="/api/upload" fileName='photos[]' @on-success="successUpload" @on-error="errorUpload"/>
```

I use laravel and vue.js and in laravel's controller I check $request['photos'] where I will have as many elements in the array as many files I uploaded

From the controller you can return the filepaths (if you want) and you will catch them in vue.js successUpload() action like in the following example:

```
methods: {
    successUpload (event) { 
      //notify
      this.$vs.notify({ color: 'success', title: 'Upload Success' })

      //get the filePaths from Laravel controller
      let filePaths = event.currentTarget.response

      //do something with the file paths...
    },
```

Also check the API of vuesax upload component.

Hope that helps.